# uniformly bounded & lipschitz continuous$\Rightarrow$ equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose we have $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ uniformly bounded on the interval $[a,b]$ and every $f_n$ is lipschitz continuous. Is it true that $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is equicontinuous?

If the answer is 'yes', why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If each $f_n$ has the same Lipschitz constant, then given epsilon, we can pick delta  regardless of $f_n$ or $x$.

Now the question becomes: Do uniformly bounded Lipschitz continuous functions have the same Lipschitz constant?

Comment: Well, I understand the first part and that's helpful! (Since we just pick $\delta$ to be $\varepsilon /L$, right?)

I know that the answer to the second part should be 'yes' (at least in my case, because the author states that they do have the same constant), but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It is yes if the Lipschitz constants are the same (equivalently, if they are bounded, you can take the sup). To see if this is always the case, consider this family {${{x}^{n}}$} on [0,1]. They are uniformly bounded by 1, and each f_n is lipschitz on [0,1]. Can I bound the set of Lipschitz constants? Maybe try graphing these functions.

Comment: Very unsure, but: since $|x_1-x_2|\geq |x_1^n-x_2^n|$, I would say that 1 would make a good upper bound for the L.constants. (But this might be wrong since I'm pretty sure you wanted to provide a counterexample...)

Comment: So, what the Lipschitz constant does is bound our secant lines.  If our derivative is bounded, we can for sure bound our secant lines by the mean value theorem.  For each ${x}^{n}$, I can bound the secant line by n (since the derivative is at most n).   If I would have gotten a constant value, or a sequence decreasing with n (like $1/n$, I would have been able to choose a maximum, and thus I could use the same Lipschitz constant, so my family would be equicontinuous.  Since I can only bound by n using the mean value theorem, and since that grows as n gets bigger, I might not be able to bound.

Comment: Graphically, look at ${x}^{n}$ as n gets big.  You can draw a steeper and steeper secant line (starting at (1,1) and a point $(1-\epsilon,{(1-\epsilon)}^{n})$

Comment: I think that does the trick! I will think this through tomorrow and accept then. (or post a comment again) Thanks so far!

Comment: I should tell you that my reasoning is not a proof; but I used what I know about Lipschitz to find a counterexample.  If you wanted a proof that the family is not equicontinuous, you would need to find a point (hint: use 1) since that given a fixed epsilon (so choose 1/2 or 1/4), I can choose n large enough so that every delta is no good for the whole family. (So no matter how close I force x to be to 1, since it is less than 1, I can choose n large enough to make it bigger than 1/2 or 1/4)

Comment: Well, I'm more interested in the case where the $f_n$ indeed have the same Lipschitz constant and you gave a nice outline how to proove it in that case. The argument you gave for why this doesn't work for arbitrary uniformly bounded L.continuous $f_n$s is completely sufficient for me. And as a final note: When I said $|x_1-x_2|\geq |x_1^n-x_2^n|$ above I was - of course - wrong... For a counterexample consider obviously $x_1=1, x_2=0.1, n=2$. It holds though for $n$ big enough...